# Converting a CGLayer to a *transparent* UIImage and PNG file in CoreGraphics iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, core-graphics

I've been making a simple painting app for the iphone. I'm trying to convert the drawn image to a transparent PNG (I don't want a white background). I'd also like to get a UIImage representation to use in a UIImageView.

Currently, I respond to touch events and draw paths to a CGLayer which is then drawn to my views context. I have access to both the CGLayer as well as the view itself. Currently, I output my view to an image using:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.bounds.size);
[drawingView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This only uses the view to create a UIImage.

Since the view has a white background it is inluded in the UIImage I create. I'd like to get a UIImage that does not have this white background so I can display and write to a PNG file.

I think I should use the CGLayer I have directly but I'm not sure how to get that from the `CGLayerRef` type I have access to.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

- Aleem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just dealt with this.  Don't draw a background on the `CGLayer` and then set the background of the `UIView` to:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

That should do it and your png will have a transparent background.

Comment: I am also stuck at this point.could you please explain your answer in more detail.Or provide a sample source code please

Comment: I'm not sure what information you need.  Could you explain further where you're having difficulty?

Comment: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myDrawView.bounds.size)
            myDrawView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(myDrawView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil)`
It doesn't save it as a PNG 