# Add MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem to UIView

Tags: ios, ios5, icons, mapkit, mkmapview

I am using a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` to toggle my MKMapView's usertrackingMode.

- Is it possible to move this button out of my Toolbar and place it on a normal UIView?
- Of course, I could implement the behavior of the button myself. Do you have any resources for the icons used in this button?

[image: MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem Icons]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems there is no way to directly add any kind of bar button item to a `UIView`.  We're going to have to subclass `UIToolbar` to make a totally invisible toolbar.  Override `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` and put *nothing*, not even a `[super drawRect]`.  Then, in init, run the following code:

```
self = [super init];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.opaque = NO;
self.translucent = YES;

return self;
```

For more details, visit this link: [Couldn't UIToolBar be transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468831/couldnt-uitoolbar-be-transparent)

Comment: Awesome... that worked well! Do you know if this could cause a rejection from the AppStore?

Comment: I don't think so...here's a list of things that Apple doesn't like: http://mobileorchard.com/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from-apple/ .  This whole thing may violate the Human Interface Guidelines, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in iOS 11, there's `MKUserTrackingButton` which is a `UIView` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link so you can create an image out of the button.  You probably want to do this as it enters multiple states:

[Create UIImage from shadowed view while retaining alpha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918237/create-uiimage-from-shadowed-view-while-retaining-alpha)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked at it, but I think my problem is different. I can't access the `UIImageView` inside the button. Is there a way to extract just the image (the arrow or arrow+heading in this case) out of a `UIBarItem`?

Comment: button.image should return the image used for the button but returns nil... see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `button.image` is supposed to return just the image, not the view...I guess Apple is using a different method to configure their `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`.