# How to fix translucent toolbar screenshot showing as black in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7

[image]

My top and bottom toolbars are showing as black when in the app they show as light gray.  I'm assuming it may have something to do with the default 'translucency checkbox' I found in the .storyboard, attributes inspector of the toolbar?

I'm using a UIActivityViewController to shoot this image out in an email.  Here's the code for grabbing the screenshot:

```
// Grab a screenshot
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *imageToShare = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found here: [iOS: what's the fastest, most performant way to make a screenshot programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964153/ios-whats-the-fastest-most-performant-way-to-make-a-screenshot-programaticall)

Seems like this should be a factory method provided by an Apple framework though.  I'm putting this a Utils.h/.m class:

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshot
{
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeZero;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        imageSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    } else {
        imageSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, window.center.x, window.center.y);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, window.transform);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x, -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -imageSize.width);
        } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.height, 0);
        } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.width, -imageSize.height);
        }
        if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
            [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        } else {
            [window.layer renderInContext:context];
        }
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set the color you on your layer before rendering it:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whateverColorYouWant];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); 
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
UIImage *imageToShare = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Take a look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048462/795245) anwser

Comment: i tried setting the background for the view as well as the toolbars and still get black.  i tried setting to white background in storyboard as well as in code too with no luck

Comment: this answer seems to solve it.  but the screenshot is huge and needs to be scaled down for my purposes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964153/ios-whats-the-fastest-most-performant-way-to-make-a-screenshot-programaticall