# iOS 7 navigationbar screenshot bug?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, screenshot

hey guys Im porting my project from ios6 to 7,
i have a function to make a screenshot of my view which has a navigation bar,
on ios6 it works fine, but on ios7 bar in screenshot becomes black

as you can see from the image, I have a navigation bar at top, a tool bar in the middle and a tab bar at the bottom,

screen shot code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

the bar is default navigation bar with clear tint clear and translucent set to YES

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

as drawing screenshot method instead.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863223) for more detailed discussion around your problem.